# MYSQL - How do I create a single query to accomplish this

Tags: mysql

I have a fairly complex situation where I'd like to see if there is a single query I can use to get the data.

In the following pseudo code, assume the "*" in each select clause has the appropriate columns selected and that table3 and table4 have similar enough columns that I can handle the diffs with padding/fake columns.

```
select * from table1 where ActiveFlag=1
for each row returned (as A)
 //check if member has a record in membership table
 select * from table2 where MembershipId=A.MembershipId
 if (row exists)
   select * from table3 where MemberId=A.MemberId
 else
   select * from table4 where MembershipId=A.MembershipId
end of for loop
```

Comment: sure, just do joins on all the tabes on membershipId.

Comment: membership is unique for each row from A? Some sample data and expected output would be great.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

This assumne each row in TableA can have 0-1 membership, otherwise we need to filter duplicates first.

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN M.MembershipId IS NULL 
             THEN T4.field1
             ELSE T3.field1
        END as field1,
        ....
        CASE WHEN M.MembershipId IS NULL 
             THEN T4.fieldN
             ELSE T3.fieldN
        END as fieldN

 FROM TableA A 
 LEFT JOIN Membership M
   ON A.MembershipId = M.MembershipId
 CROSS JOIN table3 T3
 CROSS JOIN table4 T4
 WHERE A.MemberId = T3.MemberId
    OR A.MembershipId = T4.MembershipId
```

If you have duplicate Membership replace the first two JOIN with something like this.

```
FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT TableA.*, M.MembershipId
       FROM TableA A 
       LEFT JOIN Membership M
         ON A.MembershipId = M.MembershipId
     ) A
CROSS JOIN ..
```

Comment: There must either be something different about my data or I'm translating what you have stated incorrectly, because I'm ending up with tons of duplicate data.  I think the problem is I can easily have more than one member on a membership, so that might be part of it.

Comment: Well that is my first assumtion :P. let me check again